# Selenium jSoup get data from Javascript Webpage

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, jsoup

Have asked a few questions around this recently, but haven't really found what I'm looking for.

I am trying to get all of the matches from http://www.futbol24.com/Live/?__igp=1&LiveDate=20141106 to print out, with time, home team and away team. I understand the content is loaded after the page is.

I have been told to use Selenium and then use jSoup on the result to get the data I want. Does anybody have a tutorial or some sample code they could show me, for how to do it on the website above?

Any examples would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I'm not asking for any of the above... I'm asking for an example for the specific scenario that I have mentioned?

Comment: I have only researched, not written any code. Can't seem to find the methods that I require - so wondered if anybody had done something similar before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to scrape / datamine someone's site, here are some considerations:

1. **Get permission from the site's owner!** If you do not, you will piss off the owner and get blacklisted in the best case, or be served with a lawsuit in the worst case.
2. Find out if the site exposes an [api](/questions/tagged/api). This is always the better way of scraping a site.
3. Research tools / libraries that are more appropriate for this task. Some of these include [curl](/questions/tagged/curl), [wget](/questions/tagged/wget), [httpbuilder](/questions/tagged/httpbuilder), ..... Depending on your level of comfort / knowledge, you may need to research the underlying technologies: [http](/questions/tagged/http), [rest](/questions/tagged/rest), .....
4. [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) is a functional test library for browser applications, which makes it a *poor* choice for this task.

PS: I am fully expecting for this to get downvoted / closed, because discussions / opinions are [off-topic for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\tools\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(url);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());
// Jsoup code here to parse/scrape data
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```